# What does the 'Secondary Use' key do?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm rebinding melee and skill power activation to keys closer to the WASD keys to make them more accessible. I was going to rebind Q, but by default it is set to "Secondary Use".

The only use of that key in-game that I've noticed so far is that it allows you to shop with NPCs instead of just talking to them. **Are there any other uses for this key?**

[image]

Comment: I believe it's also the "drop weapon" key, which changed from the space bar in the first game. I'm not home to confirm, though

Comment: `drop weapon` was bound to `_` by default on my install (installed yesterday evening)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondary use button is used when you can chose between multiple interactions with an NPC;like with Marcus and Dr.Zed where you can either use "E" to simply talk to them or use "Q" to enter their shop interface.

Another example is when you finish a certain quest for Claptrap and you can press "Q" to ask him for a high-five.

Answer (score 4):

As you and @dave-mcclelland mentioned, Secondary Use is used for:

- for NPCs and items that have multiple types of interactions: opening the store (like Marcus for example), giving Claptrap a high-five, turning off radios, etc.
- dropping items**

** Though right now it appears to be a bug (I assume) that even though Secondary Use can be remapped on the PC, dropping items stays with the hard-coded Q key — according to @Brysonic. I tested this in my PC copy too.

Comment: I tried rebinding the Secondary Use key to C, but the UI indicated that Q is still used for dropping items. I don't think that dropping items is part of what Secondary Use is responsible for.

Comment: @Brysonic after remapping, did you try with both C and Q? Which worked?

Comment: I tried both and only Q worked.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ is also correct - I updated my answer to include the more generic description so mine doesn't mislead. But he gets credit.